# Visual studio code Debugger not getting attached with sample express project generated by express generator

Tags: node.js, express, debugging, visual-studio-code

Node js Version :v8.11.3

VS Code version :1.29.1 x64

npm version :6.6.0

Hi ,
I have created a default express skeleton project using `express --view=jade myapp` command after that `cd myapp/` and `npm install` in the last.

Now I am trying to attach vscode debugger to this newly created project but no luck.

This is the content of my launch.json

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "protocol":"inspector",
            "port":3000,
            "program": "/home/pankaj/myfirstapp/myapp/app.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am also not able to see any error in the debug console .There is nothing in debug console neither success nor failure.

Thanks In advance

Comment: What is express skeleton project? Is it related to express.js?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful  for express default setup to set the path of `program` in launch.json to  `"program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/www"`

Answer (score 0):

Port 3000 is the application port of your express application. If you specify this in your launch configuration, the VS Code debugger will try to use it as the **debug** port (which obviously cannot work).

In addition, use VS Code variables to specify where your programs lives. E.g. if you have opened VS Code on your `myapp` directory, use `${workspaceFolder}/app.js` for the `program` attribute:

E.g.:

```
{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js"
}
```

Comment: I have modify as per your suggestion but didn't worked . @Andre Weinand